# How to query a dynamic key - mongodb schema design

Tags: mongodb, database-design, aggregation-framework

I have the following document:

```
{
    _id     : 1,

    key1    : {
                  samekeyA : "value1",
                  samekeyB : "value2"
              },

    key2 :    {
                  samekeyA : "value3",
                  samekeyB : "value4"
              },

    key3 :    {
                  samekeyA : "value5",
                  samekeyB : "value6"
              }  
}
```

Above; `key1`, `key2` and `key3` are given to demonstrate that I don't know the full key, except a prefix of it; but inner keys `samekeyA` and `samekeyB` those I know. I require queries such: `db.coll.find({"key*.samekeyA":"value1"})`.

I think there isn't a mongo way - regex key queries?- to accomplish that, so any ideas on that? Should I remodel my document -tree-?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend restructuring the model.

```
{
    _id     : 1,

    data: [   {
                  key      : "key1",
                  samekeyA : "value1",
                  samekeyB : "value2"
              },

              {
                  key      : "key2",
                  samekeyA : "value3",
                  samekeyB : "value4"
              },

              {
                  key      : "key3",
                  samekeyA : "value5",
                  samekeyB : "value6"
              }  
    ]
}
```

And the query:

```
db.col.find({"data.samekeyA": "value1"})
```

At the moment (and probably in the future, too) it's not possible to query MongoDB collections with wildcards in fieldnames (thanks to @gWiz).

Comment: That is to say: no, MongoDB doesn't have any such query operator that allows you to match fields against a regex.

Answer (score 8):

**Using MongoDB 3.4.4 and newer versions:**

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    { "$replaceRoot": {
        "newRoot": {
            "$arrayToObject": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
                    "as": "el",
                    "cond": {
                        "$eq": [
                            "$$el.v.samekeyA",
                            "value1"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    } }
])
```

---

The above pipeline will yield the final output

```
{
    "key1" : {
        "samekeyA" : "value1",
        "samekeyB" : "value2"
    }
}
```

---

### Explanations

The pipeline can be decomposed to show each individual operator's results.

**[`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)**

**[`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)** enables you to transform the root document with dynamic keys 
(denoted by the system variable **[`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT)**) into an array that contains a element for each field/value pair in the original document. Each element in the return array is a document that contains two fields k and v.
Running the pipeline with just the operator in a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)** stage

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "keys": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" }
    } }
])
```

yields

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "keys" : [ 
        {
            "k" : "_id",
            "v" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "key1",
            "v" : {
                "samekeyA" : "value1",
                "samekeyB" : "value2"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "key2",
            "v" : {
                "samekeyA" : "value3",
                "samekeyB" : "value4"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "key3",
            "v" : {
                "samekeyA" : "value5",
                "samekeyB" : "value6"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)**

The **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)** operator acts as a filtering mechanism for the array produced by the **[`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)** operator, works by selecting a subset of the array to return based on the specified condition which 
becomes your query.

Consider the following pipeline which returns an array of the key/value pair that matches the condition `{ "samekeyA": "value1" }`

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "keys": { 
            "$filter": {
                "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
                "as": "el",
                "cond": {
                    "$eq": [
                        "$$el.v.samekeyA",
                        "value1"
                    ]
                }
            }  
        }
    } }
])
```

which yields

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "keys" : [ 
        {
            "k" : "key1",
            "v" : {
                "samekeyA" : "value1",
                "samekeyB" : "value2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**[`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)**

This will transform the filtered array above from

```
[ 
    {
        "k" : "key1",
        "v" : {
            "samekeyA" : "value1",
            "samekeyB" : "value2"
        }
    }
]
```

to the original document with the dynamic key

```
{
    "key1" : {
        "samekeyA" : "value1",
        "samekeyB" : "value2"
    }
}
```

so running the pipeline

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "key": {
            "$arrayToObject": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
                    "as": "el",
                    "cond": {
                        "$eq": [
                            "$$el.v.samekeyA",
                            "value1"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    } }
])
```

will produce

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "key1" : {
            "samekeyA" : "value1",
            "samekeyB" : "value2"
        }
    }
}
```

**[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/#pipe._S_replaceRoot)**

This will promote the filtered dynamic key document to the top level and replaces all other fields. The operation replaces all existing fields in the input document, including the `_id` field.

Essentially this transforms the above document

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "key1" : {
            "samekeyA" : "value1",
            "samekeyB" : "value2"
        }
    }
}
```

to the desired final output

```
{
    "key1" : {
        "samekeyA" : "value1",
        "samekeyB" : "value2"
    }
}
```