# MongoDb get record based on dynamic keys

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a dynamic schema. In below schema "ABC", "WQA" are dynamic keys. I want to get records of those customers whose source is "sourceX" and want to show only "CustomerId" and "code".

I am a beginner in MongoDB domain. I tried different solutions like
[How to query a dynamic key - mongodb schema design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082606/how-to-query-a-dynamic-key-mongodb-schema-design)
but couldn't achieve desire output. Kindly guide me here.

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5f0339e28fbb15b9f8a17181"), 
 "CustomerID" : "12345", 
 "ABC":[
   {
        "datetime" : ISODate("2020-06-13"), 
        "source" : "SourceX", 
        "code" : "ABC", 
   },
   {
       "datetime" : ISODate("2020-08-18"), 
       "source" : "SourceB", 
       "code" : "ABC",  
   }
  ],
"WQA":[
    {
        "datetime" : ISODate("2020-02-16"), 
        "source" : "SourceX", 
        "code" : "WQA", 
   },
   {
       "datetime" : ISODate("2020-03-16"), 
       "source" : "SourceY", 
       "code" : "WQA",  
   }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following aggregation pipeline would be able to achieve what you're looking for, note however that this isn't a very mongo-friendly data format. https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZRcbzEe1bkR

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      CustomerID: 1,
      entries: {
        $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$entries"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$entries.v"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "entries.v.source": "SourceX"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      CustomerID: 1,
      code: "$entries.v.code"
    }
  }
])
```

---

If you are able to, I strongly suggest you change your data to just have a single array, in which case you can easily utilize indexes to speed up queries. The following setup could utilize an index on `codes.source` to heavily speed up the initial match. https://mongoplayground.net/p/hBC1F-g9af1

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5f0339e28fbb15b9f8a17181"),
  "CustomerID": "12345",
  "codes": [
    {
      "datetime": ISODate("2020-06-13"),
      "source": "SourceX",
      "code": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "datetime": ISODate("2020-08-18"),
      "source": "SourceB",
      "code": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "datetime": ISODate("2020-02-16"),
      "source": "SourceX",
      "code": "WQA"
    },
    {
      "datetime": ISODate("2020-03-16"),
      "source": "SourceY",
      "code": "WQA"
    }
  ]
}
```

And then you could use a slightly modified aggregation pipeline to achieve the result you want.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "codes.source": "SourceX"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$codes"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "codes.source": "SourceX"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      CustomerID: 1,
      code: "$codes.code"
    }
  }
])
```